# Python iter function is not working without sentinel value for a normal function

Tags: python, iterator, generator

Here I defined a normal function:

```
def abc():
  return 1
```

Now when I am iterating using iter function on abc method, I am getting the following error.

```
for i in iter(abc):
  print i

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

But now when I am using sentinel, its working.

```
 for i in iter(abc, ''):
  print i

1
1
1
1
1
1
...
```

Any idea why the above behaviour happening ?

Comment: Did you read the _documentation_ ? https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter  It is explained it it ... why ask here? `If the second argument, sentinel, is given, then object must be a callable object. The iterator created in this case will call object with no arguments for each call to its __next__() method; if the value returned is equal to sentinel, StopIteration will be raised, otherwise the value will be returned.`

Comment: missed checking it. Thanks for pointing out @PatrickArtner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`iter(spam)` expects `spam` to be an iterable, which a function object is not.

`iter(spam, sentinel)` expects `spam` to be a callable, which it is.  So `iter` will call `spam` until it returns the sentinel value.

Answer (score 3):

```
Docstring:
iter(iterable) -> iterator
iter(callable, sentinel) -> iterator

Get an iterator from an object.  In the first form, the argument must
supply its own iterator, or be a sequence.
In the second form, the callable is called until it returns the sentinel.
```

So you chose the second form, which means it will forever loop until the sentinel in this case `''` is returned.